# SQL latest date and event

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to pull the latest date that a specific event occurred. In the DB I have a test that was completed multiple times by each user. I want only when the last test result a user had was under 200.

```
create table #temp_VL (cln_urn varchar(50), tst_date datetime, tst_df_test_name varchar (50), VL DECIMAL (10,2), cln_pk varchar(100))
```

Is the table that I am importing my data into. The problem that I am having is that some people tested below 200 at some point, but went back above 200 later. I can pull all people who have tested below 200, but for some reason not when that is the last date.

Comment: Can't picture what you're asking.  Please illustrate with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirement correctly, that is:

> Give me the most recent record for each user where that users score is less than 200

The following code shows an example of achieving this:

```
DECLARE @tabTestResults TABLE
    (
        UserId INT,
        TestDate DATE,
        Result INT
    )

INSERT
INTO    @tabTestResults
        (
            UserId,
            TestDate,
            Result
        )
VALUES  ( 1, '2015-01-01', 180 ),
        ( 1, '2015-07-23', 200 ),
        ( 1, '2015-08-23', 190 ),
        ( 1, '2015-09-23', 210 ),
        ( 2, '2015-01-01', 210 ),
        ( 2, '2015-10-23', 190 ),
        ( 3, '2015-10-23', 170 ),
        ( 4, '2015-10-23', 220 )


SELECT  UserId, TestDate, Result
FROM
        (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY TestDate DESC) AS RowNumber, *
            FROM    @tabTestResults
            WHERE   Result < 200
        ) SQ
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

Returning:

```
UserId  TestDate    Result
1       2015-08-23  190
2       2015-10-23  190
3       2015-10-23  170
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want **only** that users that were rated under 200 in the last date as you expressed.

> I want only when the last test result a user had was under 200.

You can use the below query.

```
with CTE as
(
    select 1 UsrID, '2015-08-01' [Date], 190 rate
    union
    select 1 UsrID, '2015-08-02' [Date], 290 rate
    union
    select 2 UsrID, '2015-08-03' [Date], 190 rate
    union
    select 3 UsrID, '2015-08-04' [Date], 390 rate
    union
    select 3 UsrID, '2015-08-07' [Date], 150 rate
    union
    select 4 UsrID, '2015-08-09' [Date], 140 rate
)

select CTE.UsrID,CTE.Date,CTE.rate
from CTE
inner join
    (
    select UsrID,max(Date) maxdate
    from CTE
    group by UsrID
    ) dt
on CTE.UsrID = dt.UsrID and CTE.Date = dt.maxdate
where rate < 200
```

Using the data I put as example you will get this:

```
UsrID   Date    rate
2   2015-08-03  190
3   2015-08-07  150
4   2015-08-09  140
```

Comment: @JFulton: Nice! so if you think it can help you select my answer as correct by clicking on the correct symbol at the right side of my answer.